# How to solve 'Exception was thrown' error in Flutter when using TensorFlow Lite for image classification?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to flutter, i build a aplication that do image classification using tensorflowlite, the      app run ok but when i try to put another model with better accuracy it trows an error clasification      one of the classes, here is what trows:
`When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: \#0      \_Array.\[\] (dart:core-patch/array.dart:10:36) \#1      \_HomeState.build (package:Diagnostico_Artritis/home.dart:142:62) \#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27) \#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15) \#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11) \#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5) \#6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19) \#7      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21) \#8      RendererBinding.\_handlePersistentFrameCallback         (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)   \#9      SchedulerBinding.\_invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15) \#10     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9) \#11     SchedulerBinding.\_handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5) \#12     \_invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13) \#13     PlatformDispatcher.\_drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5) \#14     \_drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)`
i try with another model but the error just keep keep appearing